# Looking for better defined range on Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for help to make my macro more range-friendly. Excel is 2010 version.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AddressList").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AddressList").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "G2:G1374"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,    
DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AddressList").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:J1374")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Question: How to change from predefined range (G2:G1374 and A1:J1374) to something based on columns and used cells?

Comment: You'd use something like ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AddressList").columns(1) and ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AddressList").columns(6), you'll need to resize to get row 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to code a [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx). Using the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) is ideal for referencing a block of data radiating out from A1.

```
with worksheets("AddressList")  
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(7), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    end with    
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
Dim mySheet as worksheet
Set mySheet = Sheets("somePrettySheetName")

with mySheet
    .range(.cells(row,column),.cells(row,Column)).someStuffToDo

end with
```

if dont wana use with, you need to specify sheet all time e.g.

```
mySheet.range(mySheet.cells(row,column),mySheet.cells(row,column))
```

remark: row and column can be numbers, letters etc...